# Call to undefined method codeigniter Modeloproduccion::obtener_produccion_por_id()

Tags: php, function, model, controller, codeigniter-3

```
UPDATE: ITS WORKING NOW, A ERROR IN MY MODAL. SORRY.
```

i have a little problem with my controller or my model i dont know but i need your help. I im gettin error

> Call to undefined method Modeloproduccion::obtener_produccion_por_id()

Here is my controller **Produccion.php**

```
 function actualizar()
{
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $data['main_title'] = 'Proyectos';
    $data['title2'] = 'Ver/Editar Proyecto';
    // Obtenemos el id de la editorial a editar
    $id = $this->input->post('id');
    $resultado = $this->modeloproduccion->obtener_produccion_por_id($id);
```

And this is my model **Modeloproduccion.php**

```
 function obtener_produccion_por_id($id)
    {
        $this->db->where('id', $id);
        $query = $this->db->get('produccion');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
```

Any idea?

Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

have you load the model?
To do that you must add

```php
$this->load->model('modeloproduccion');
```

before you use the model.

Edit: according to [documentation](https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/general/models.html) of Codeigniter3 there is no problem with case.

Comment: Yes i have

<?php
class Produccion extends CI_Controller{
  function __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->load->model('modeloproduccion');

Comment: @Pixysve can i see your full model?

Answer (score 0):

$this->load->model('Modeloproduccion');